# Get child name instead of position id in Expandable List View

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am following [this](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)tutorial to implement an Expandable List View. Now my question is, how would I change the following method to get the child name instead of the child position id?

```
// Call when child row clicked
        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            /****** When Child row clicked then this function call *******/

            // Log.i("Noise",
            // "parent == "+groupPosition+"=  child : =="+childPosition);
            if (ChildClickStatus != childPosition) {
                ChildClickStatus = childPosition;

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Parent :" + groupPosition + " Child :" + childPosition,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            return childPosition;
        }
```

I already try it 2 hours to get this work.

Comment: Sorry I am beginner and idk what you mean exactly by define child name. I inserted in toast section final Child child = new Child(); and then "Child :" + child.getName(). But result is NULL. ???

Comment: `Child child = new Child()` what do you expect this to do?

Comment: call defined method getName from this class

Comment: certainly, but this newly created instance is unlikely to contain any kind of data in its members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as the child and put the declaration here

```
getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) { 
    final Child child = parent.getChildren().get(childPosition);
    //The rest of your method...
}
```

Comment: It is already in the code the tutorial provides ;) in the getChildView method.

Comment: yeah just saw it :D...thank you anyway for your hint

Comment: hi just got another issue. When the activty starts and I expand one parent then first it shows all children in the toast message successively. how could I avoid that and the toast should only be shown when I click on a single child?

Comment: Maybe because the parent has a child which is a parent itself. So the second parent calls all its children. Try to set a breakpoint at the line you think the toast is coming from and debug your code then you should get on the right track.